# Where is Meteor installed on Windows?

Tags: meteor

Hi I've just installed Meteor on Windows 7. Using the command prompt I was hoping I'd just type meteor but that's not working (not recognized). Do I need to set PATH?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\.meteor\

You can also set that in your PATH when it is missing there.

Comment: The installation had added it to PATH but I had to reboot before it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On windows its installed here

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor
```

but `meteor`  command does not work sometime. To make `meteor` command working you need to modify path variables as follows.

Automatically set Path (after installation)

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor\
```

Modification (remove backslash)

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor
```