# Meteor is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on Windows 8.1

Tags: meteor, windows-8.1

This is the output that is showing when I'm trying to use meteor on the command line: '"C:\Users\Javier\AppData.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.8t-os.windows.x86_32\meteor.bat"'

I don't know what to do and I don't know how to "play" with the path. Nothing.

Comment: Have you opened a new console window since installing?  Restarted your computer?

Comment: The error message is included in the description. Thank's for your help @Ross .

Comment: Please make sure the path [where meteor is installed on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616277/where-is-meteor-installed-on-windows) is included in the [Windows PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: Thank you! @ElderSmash It works.

Comment: Unable to comment yet, but I wanted to mention that in addition to Lokinder Singh Chauhan's answer you will need to reboot your PC in order for the changes to work as jamc92 mentioned. Also, the path was not set automatically by the installer on my Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 19):

On my Windows 10 machine after installing meteor, path was set automatically, but meteor command was not working. I found there was backslash at the end of path variable, I removed it and meteor command worked. See the example below:

BEFORE

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor\
```

AFTER

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor
```

Comment: same as on windows 7 i can confirm.. that worked thanks :)

Comment: Works on Windows 11 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can try running your command line as administrator. That's if you are developing on Windows

Answer (score 4):

I set this in my PATH

C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local.meteor\

Reboot and it works!

Answer (score 4):

After installation, for the PATH environment variable to be loaded with the correct value, you need to close the cmd prompt and restart it.

Comment: next time, please explain why you advise to do so

Answer (score 0):

After an hour agonizing with the installer, I finally solved the problem with some easy steps:

- Enter in the dir "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Package Cache"
- Look for file called "SetupMeteor.msi" -> Right click and Uninstall.
- After the .msi finally uninstall all meteor files and registries, you MUST REMOVE the folder "\Package Cache" in "AppData\Local" folder.

Now, just run the InstallMeteor.exe downloaded from meteor.com and be happy :)

No restart required in my case (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was opening Visual Studio code as an administrator and retrying the operation